# How can I check if the user entered "enter" on the keyboard? (C)

Tags: c

I would like to stop the loop when the user enters "enter" on the keyboard.
ps : `ch[k-1]!='e'` appears because I didn't know how to stop it otherwise.

```
while (ch[k - 1] != 'e') {
    if (is_palindrome(ch, k) == true && count == 0) {
        temp = present_array_as_integer(ch, k);
        count = 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {
         /* moves the indexes in the array from left to right
          * and leaves the last index empty */
        ch[i] = ch[i + 1];
    }
    scanf(" %c", &ch[k - 1]);
}
```

Comment: Don't put space at the begining of the format string. That makes it skip over whitespace, which includes newline.

Comment: Why don't you scanf an enter key press in debug mode and see what the value is?

Comment: Instead of reading one character at a time, read a whole line with `fgets()`.

Comment: @Yasmin12 did my answer work?

Answer (score 0):

The `newline` character in C/C++ is `'\n'`. So in theory you only need to check:

```
while (ch[k-1] != '\n')
```

However, I would suggest changing this:

```
scanf(" %c", &ch[k - 1]);
```

into this:

```
scanf("%c", &ch[k - 1]);
```

Or you can use `gets_s()` for reading all the string and then parse it char by char.

Comment: `gets` is dangerous, and removed from the language (C11).

Comment: @IljaEverilä thanks for the reminder I updated the answer